# Delete JSON data using PHP While clicking on a button in a HTML table

Tags: php, json

I was trying to delete the JSON entry from the JSON file while clicking a button that is in an HTML table[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC9Rb.png)

and my JSON data:[{"room_id":"1","room_type":"Duplex","room_location":"North","room_charge":"45","room_status":"available","payment_status":"not paid"},{"room_id":"2","room_type":"Singlex","room_location":"South","room_charge":"54","room_status":"available","payment_status":"not paid"},{"room_id":"3","room_type":"Duplex","room_location":"East","room_charge":"45","room_status":"available","payment_status":"not paid"},]
and here is my code for creating the table part

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
        <tr>
        <th>Room ID</th>
        <th>Room Type</th>
        <th>Room Location</th>
        <th>Room Charge</th>
        <th>Room Status</th>
        <th>Payment Status</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <?PHP
         $data = file_get_contents("room-data.json");
         $data = json_decode($data, true);
         foreach($data as $row)
                             {
         echo '<form action="" method="post">
        <tr>
        <td name="room_id">'.$row["room_id"].'</td>
        <td name="room_type">'.$row["room_type"].'</td>
        <td name="room_location">'.$row["room_location"].
        '</td><td name="room_charge">'.$row["room_charge"].'</td>
        <td name="room_status">'.$row["room_status"].'</td>
        <td name="payment_status">'.$row["payment_status"].'</td>
        <td name="update">'."Update".'</td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="delete">'."Delete".'</button></td>
        </tr>
        </form>';
       }

      ?>


      </table>

      </div>
```

So when I will click on the button the respective JSON data for that delete button will also delete and I want to do that using PHP
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Onclick function something like :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
//edit your buttun to this :
<td><a href="javascript:void(0)"><button onclick="delet('.$row["room_id"].')" type="submit" name="delete">'."Delete".'</button></a></td>
//your delet fucn
<script>
        function delet(id){
            jQuery.ajax({
             url:'delet_page.php',
                type:'post',
                data:'type=submit&room_id='+id,
                success:function(result){
                window.location.href=window.location.href 
            
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

And then your delet_page.php should be like :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['room_id'])){
//get room id post
$room_id=$_POST['room_id']; 
// read json file
$data = file_get_contents('room-data.json');

// decode json to associative array
$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);

// get array index to delete
$arr_index = array();
foreach ($json_arr as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value['room_id'] == $room_id)
    {
        $arr_index[] = $key;
    }
}

// delete data
foreach ($arr_index as $i)
{
    unset($json_arr[$i]);
}

// rebase array
$json_arr = array_values($json_arr);

// encode array to json and save to file
file_put_contents('room-data.json', json_encode($json_arr));
}
```